# What is the highest "hikeable" mountain in the world?

Tags: hiking, mountaineering, mountains

What is the highest mountain in the world that can be hiked all the way up?
That you can go up to the top without any sort of experience climbing.

Comment: There are quite a few questions and answers to this topic already - just search for "Aconcagua" and you'll pull up at least 3.

Comment: Aconcagua is marginal for someone with no mountaineering experience.  As for "little", that is pretty vague.  But the question itself could use some work.  For example, acclimitization is a technical consideration, as is identifying pulmonary edema or cerebral edema, even if the mountain could be climbed as a mere hike.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "without any sort of experience climbing."  To climb a high mountain safely involves more than an easy trail; it involves experience with the effects of altitude on your body.

Comment: I mean no climbing gear, no experience doing any actual climbing.

Comment: Note that a lack of "actual climbing" does not mean one can safely do it even if they are at the apex of physical condition.  High altitudes are known to destroy even the most skilled and physically fit athletes.  I've seen it too many times to count.

Comment: Talking about the 5000s, proper acclimatisation is a requirement but definitely not part of the grading

Answer (score 10):

It’s probably not THE highest, but Kilimanjaro at 5895 meters is a pretty famous one that doesn’t require any particular skill, just basic conditioning.

That said, I am reading 'climbing' as the physical process in your question. You still need to know about altitude acclimitization to go this high.

Answer (score 2):

Candidate:  [Cerro Toco](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cerro_Toco), 18,386 feet (5,604 meters), an easy drive from San Pedro de Atacama, which is a pleasant town in Chile with good places to stay and eat. You can drive to about 17,000 feet.  The radiotelescope array at Chajnantor is visible from a lookout point on the road up to the parking spot.

The caveat is:  Is this really a mountain?  It is the highest peak in its vicinity, it has a name, and cerro means hill or mountain in Spanish, but by Andes standards it is a hill.

Nothing remotely resembling technical climbing is required.  A pair of hiking poles is advisable on the snowy part of the descent -- or at least what was a snow slope in 2007.

**Warning:**  Acclimitization is a technical climbing skill, as is identifying pulmonary edema or cerebral edema, even if the mountain could be climbed as a mere hike. I made this point in a comment under the Question, and @RockPapertz-Mask it or Casket also did in a comment below.  At the very least, spend the night before at San Pedro de Atacama (over 8,000 feet).  This problem is less dangerous on Cerro Toco than many other peaks because there is only a 1,500 feet or so very easy climb down, and then a quick descent by car to San Pedro.  But you have to know enough to be aware. Read up before hiking up!   Better, get some experience hiking at altitudes of, say, 12,000 feet -- easy to do in California or the Rockies.  But even if you are fine at 12,000 or 14,000 feet, you may be in trouble a thousand feet higher.

Comment: Cerro Toco also has a prominance of close to 500 meters, that's enough.

Comment: Note that technical climbing may not be required, but the ability to handle breathing at that altitude is ***essential***.  I can't count the number of people I've encountered who have serious health problems at altitudes much lower that Cerro Toco.

Answer (score 0):

In Europe, the highest you can get without *any* effort is the "Klein Matterhorn" at 3883m. It has a cable car to the top. And then there are some other very high places you can get even with flip-flops or high-heels if you wish, such as Titlis or most famously the Jungfraujoch.

I need to add that I do not recommend wearing such poor footwear up there. It's still only 5-10 C even in summer and outside of the cable station the path is snow or ice.

Comment: I would not call this a hiking peak. If you do not use the cable car, you have to travel a glacier (not recommended, there is lots of garbage from the ski resort). The highest hiking peaks in the alps are Groß Bigerhorn and Äußeres Barrhorn, depending on your definition of a mountain. Bigerhorn is slightly higher but only a minor bump in the Balfrid ridge while Barrhorn is a proper mountain by all definitions.

Comment: With the snow fields retreating Lagginhorn 4010m is also a good candidate for a hiking peak. The west ridge can now be done without crampons or ice axes and given that the scrambling is not too hard, this could also be graded as a T5 hike

Comment: @Manziel My point was that when you _do_ use the cable car, you can get quite high without any experience in climbing or hiking at all.

Comment: You can beat this easily by car. Pikes Peak comes immediately to my mind and there are some places in South America where you can go even higher

Answer (score 0):

[Mt Kinabalu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_Kinabalu) (4,095 m) in Malysian Borneo can be "climbed" with no particular climbing experience, although a certain level of fitness is required (and it is compulsory for a guide to accompany each party).  Not as high as Mt Kilimanjaro, but less likely for unacclimated climbers to experience altitude sickness.